# In $.Deferred.done() called to soon

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

This an example to show my problem.

```
$.fn.Heartbeat = function(){
  console.log('started');
  $.ajax({
    url:baseurl.php,
    .
    .
    .
    success: function(data){
      //DO SOME STUFF
      console.log('end of success');
    }
} 

$.when($('.mydiv').Heartbeat()).done(function(){console.log('after done');});
```

This code outputs:

`started`

`after done`

`end of success`

While I want:

`started`

`end of success`

`after done`

I mean, the function inside DONE must be executed after Heartbeat completes otherwise it's not DONE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.when()` is not magic.  It doesn't know when some function passed to it is done.  Instead you must pass it a promise and it will then know when that promise is done.  Because you aren't returning the promise from your `Hearbeat()` function, `$.when()` has no idea when that ajax call is actually done and thus it treats it as a synchronous event.

Here's a much simpler way to do this:

```
var Heartbeat = function(){
  console.log('started');
  return $.ajax({
    url:baseurl.php,
    // other args
  }).then(function(data) {
        //DO SOME STUFF
        console.log('end of success');
  });
} 

Heartbeat().done(function(){
   console.log('after done');
});
```

Changes:

1. You have to return the promise from Heartbeat so `.done()` can wait for it
2. No need to use `$.when()` for a single promise - just use `.then()` on that promise.
3. `Heartbeat` is a regular function (not a jQuery method) so you call it as a regular function.  Since the function doesn't use the jQuery object in any way, I don't see any reason to make it a jQuery method.
4. Switch success handler to use `.then()` since you're using promises
5. Fix parens and bracing to be legal JS

Comment: It worked, I tested it with done instead of then. Howerver I don't understand the big lesson here. What happens if I don't use return? Doesn't Heartbeat.done() should wait for Heartbeat() to complete?

Comment: @Ferex done works as well, adeneo's answer works as well. If you copy the code, paste it in the console, change 'baseurl.php' to '' and run it on this page you see it works just fine. Why do you think Heartbeat should return something? You need to pass something to `where` or you invoke `done` on something. If Heartbeat doesn't return something you're trying to invoke done on `undefined` or pass udefined to where.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but doesn't every function returns something?? This what I thought: if there is no return expression a function returns true when it completes without errors, false in other cases.

Comment: No. Any function that makes no explicit return will return `undefined`.

Comment: @Ferex - a function without an explicit return statement returns `undefined` so you were passing `undefined` to `$.when()`.  `$.when()` waits for the promises passed to it to complete.  If you don't pass it any promises, it thinks everything must be done already so it executes the `.done()` callback immediately rather than waiting for the ajax call to complete.

Comment: @Ferex - The big lesson here is that the ajax call completes asynchronously (some undefined time in the future) long after the Heartbeart function has returned.  If you want to use promises so that you can know when the ajax function is done, then you must return the promise from `Heartbeat` so that the caller of `Heartbeat` can use that promise to be notified when the ajax call inside of `Heartbeat` is finally done.

Answer (score 2):

That's a strange way to do it, but firstly you need to add the `Heartbeat` function to jQuery's prototype to be able to chain it.

Secondly, you need to return the promise from the ajax function to `$.when`, only then will the `done` callback be executed when the promise resolves, like this

```
$.fn.Heartbeat = function () {
    console.log('started');
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'baseurl.php',
        success: function (data) {
            //DO SOME STUFF
            console.log('end of success');
        }
    });
}

$.when($('.mydiv').Heartbeat()).done(function () {
    console.log('after done');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/2q933p0s/1/)

---

To send an ajax request for each element, and resolve the promise once all requests have finished successfully, you can do

```
$.fn.Heartbeat = function () {
    console.log('started');

    var def = new Deferred();

    $.when.apply(undefined, 
        $.map(this, function() {
            return $.ajax({
                url: '/echo/html/',
                success: function (data) {
                    //DO SOME STUFF
                    console.log('end of success');
                }
            });
        })
    ).then(def.resolve);

    return def.promise();
}

$('.mydiv').Heartbeat().done(function () {
    console.log('after done');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, in my code I already had $.fn.Heartbeat, however it doesn't work even if I return the promise

Comment: @Ferex It does work, adeneo's code is one word different than the code you posted in your question and it works. The reason why it doesn't work for you I guess is that the xhr fails and it only prints out `started` or you're using code that you didn't post so nobody can even make a guess as to what's going wrong since you didn't post the code and didn't say in your comment what's going wrong. `It doesn't work` is not a way to describe your problem.

Comment: And you don't need `$.when()`. `$('.mydiv').heartbeat().done(...)` will do the job. (Note - I changed the 'H' to lower case). [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2q933p0s/2/).